# Table two Rows select all where value equals condition

Tags: sql, database, select, h2, where-clause

I have a table called flights.
In this table i have many columns. I want to select value out of these two columns:

```
TAILNUM, DEP_DELAY
```

Each TAILNUM has a lot of entrys in the table.
I want to select all TAILNUM's where the DEP_TIME is equal to 0, but ONLY if the same DEP_TIME from each TAILNUM in each row equals 0. If it has a diffrent number than 0 it must NOT show.

I tried this but this only shows me the value where the DEP_TIME is equal to 0 but not if it's always 0.

```
select TAILNUM, DEP_DELAY
from flights
WHERE DEP_DELAY = 0
order by TAILNUM DESC
```

This is what the table looks like:
[Short cutout of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8bdm.png)

I tried many diffrent things and i would be really grateful for any advise. Thanks!

Comment: TAILNUMs or  DEP_DELAY = 0? Edit your question and clarify.

Comment: sorry DEP_TIME i changed it

Comment: *I want to select all TAILNUM's that are equal to 0, but ONLY if the same TAILNUM in each row equals 0.* What did you change?

Comment: i changed it now i forgot to change the upper part aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select TAILNUM
from flights
group by TAILNUM
having min(DEP_DELAY) = 0 and max(DEP_DELAY)  = 0
order by TAILNUM DESC;
```

This returns `TAILNUM`s where the only value for `DEP_DELAY` is `0`.  If `DEP_DELAY` is never negative, you can simplify this to:

```
having max(DEP_DELAY)  = 0
```